# Problema con javascript puro, formularios y campos dinamicos

Tags: javascript, formularios

Tengo un formulario al que voy agregando campos de forma dinámica desde javascript usando la función `document.createElement()` para crearlos, luego uso la función `formulario.appendChild()` para agregarlos como hijos del formulario en cuestión.

El problema surge cuando al querer introducir mis campos dentro de los DIV que estoy usando para organizarlos visualmente también uso la función `div.appendChild()` entonces mis campos se disocian del formulario y al enviar el formulario al script PHP que lo procesará estos campos no están presentes en el `$_POST`.

Probé haciéndolo al revés, es decir,primero  los introduje dentro del `DIV`, pero luego al agregarlos al formulario ya no me aparecen dentro de sus `DIV` respectivos pero si están presentes en el `$_POST`. No se qué hacer :(

Aquí mi formulario html

```js
function agregarFila() {
  var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
  var divContenedor = document.getElementById("divContenedor");
  var campoCantFilas = document.getElementById("campoCantFilas");

  campoCantFilas.value++;

  var divFila = document.createElement('div');
  var divNombre = document.createElement('div');
  var divNota = document.createElement('div');

  var campoNombre = document.createElement('input');
  var campoNota = document.createElement('input');

  divFila.id = "fila" + campoCantFilas.value;
  divNombre.id = "divNombre" + campoCantFilas.value;
  divNota.id = "divNota" + campoCantFilas.value;

  campoNombre.type = "text";
  campoNombre.name = "nombre" + campoCantFilas.value;
  campoNombre.id = "nombre" + campoCantFilas.value;

  campoNombre.type = "text";
  campoNombre.name = "nota" + campoCantFilas.value;
  campoNota.id = "nota" + campoCantFilas.value;

  formulario.appendChild(campoNombre);
  formulario.appendChild(campoNota);

  divNombre.appendChild(campoNombre);
  divNota.appendChild(campoNota);

  divFila.appendChild(divNombre);
  divFila.appendChild(divNota);
}

function iniciarFormulario() {
  var divAgregar = document.getElementById("divAgregar");

  divAgregar.addEventListener("click", agregarFila, false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", iniciarFormulario);
```

```html
<FORM action="procesa.php" method=post name=formulario id=formulario>
    <DIV id=divContenedor>
        <INPUT type=hidden name=campoCantFilas id=campoCantFilas value=0>
        <DIV id=divAgregar>Agregar</DIV>
        
        <DIV id=fila0>
            <DIV id=divNombre0>Nombre: <INPUT type=text name=nombre0 id=nombre0></DIV>
            <DIV id=divNota0>Nota: <INPUT type=text name=nota0 id=nota0></DIV>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
    
    <DIV id=divSubmit>
        <INPUT type=submit name=procesar id=procesar value=Procesar>
    </DIV>
</FORM>
```

y parte del codigo php que procesa los datos del formulario

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    
    if(isset($_POST["procesar"])) {
        $cantidadFilas = $_POST["campoCantFilas"];
        $nombres = array();
        $notas = array();
        
        for($i=0; $i<$cantidadFilas; $i++) {
            $nombres[$i] = $_POST["nombre$i"]
            $notas[$i] = $_POST["nota$i"]
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Tal vez quieras incluir ejemplos de código. Para empezar, el código `html`, `js` y `php` que te está dando problemas.

Comment: Hola gracias por la sugerencia, ya he editado la pregunta y he agregado los códigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estas "*colgando*" las partes de forma incorrecta.

Deberías hacerlo así:

- `divNombre` debería tener a `campoNombre`
- `divNota` debería tener a `campoNota`
- `divFila` debería tener a `divNombre` y a `divNota`
- `divContenedor` debería tener a `divFila`

Así mismo te estaría faltando agregar los texto `Nombre:`  y `Nota:` , dentro de `divNombre` y `divNota` respectivamente, por lo que me tome la libertad de agregarlos.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function agregarFila() {
  var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
  var divContenedor = document.getElementById("divContenedor");
  var campoCantFilas = document.getElementById("campoCantFilas");

  campoCantFilas.value++;

  var divFila = document.createElement('div');
  var divNombre = document.createElement('div');
  var divNota = document.createElement('div');

  var textNombre = document.createElement('span');
  var campoNombre = document.createElement('input');
  var textNota = document.createElement('span');
  var campoNota = document.createElement('input');
  
  textNombre.innerText = 'Nombre: ';
  textNota.innerText = 'Nota: ';

  divFila.id = "fila" + campoCantFilas.value;
  divNombre.id = "divNombre" + campoCantFilas.value;
  divNota.id = "divNota" + campoCantFilas.value;

  campoNombre.type = "text";
  campoNombre.name = "nombre" + campoCantFilas.value;
  campoNombre.id = "nombre" + campoCantFilas.value;

  campoNombre.type = "text";
  campoNombre.name = "nota" + campoCantFilas.value;
  campoNota.id = "nota" + campoCantFilas.value;

  divNombre.appendChild(textNombre);
  divNombre.appendChild(campoNombre);
  
  divNota.appendChild(textNota);
  divNota.appendChild(campoNota);

  divFila.appendChild(divNombre);
  divFila.appendChild(divNota);

  divContenedor.appendChild(divFila);
}

function iniciarFormulario() {
  var divAgregar = document.getElementById("divAgregar");

  divAgregar.addEventListener("click", agregarFila, false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", iniciarFormulario);
```

```html
<FORM action="procesa.php" method=post name=formulario id=formulario>
    <DIV id=divContenedor>
        <INPUT type=hidden name=campoCantFilas id=campoCantFilas value=0>
        <DIV id=divAgregar>Agregar</DIV>
        
        <DIV id=fila0>
            <DIV id=divNombre0>Nombre: <INPUT type=text name=nombre0 id=nombre0></DIV>
            <DIV id=divNota0>Nota: <INPUT type=text name=nota0 id=nota0></DIV>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
    
    <DIV id=divSubmit>
        <INPUT type=submit name=procesar id=procesar value=Procesar>
    </DIV>
</FORM>
```